# Errors when adding interruptible regions in an activity diagram in IBM Rhapsody

Tags: uml, activity-diagram, rhapsody, sysml

I have the following activity Diagram that I made in IBM Rhapsody:

[image]

I can simulate without issues. But when I want to add an interruptible region, I get the following errors :
[image]

And Obviously I am not able to simulate.

Could you please tell me what am I missing here ?

Comment: It reads _Activity_, So likely you are i the wong environmrnt. They must be actions!

Comment: Sorry @qwerty_so , I don't get your point. 
Could you explain more what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: Although the diagram says Action, the error says Activity. So they are probably not Actions. Both render the same way.

Comment: Mmm, I'm pretty sure those are actions, evidence is that I can simulate before adding the interruptible region without issues.

Comment: I was only speculating. Axel is an expert and you should go with his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Rhapsody simulation doesn't support interruptible regions. This would be consistent with the [fUML-specification](https://www.omg.org/spec/FUML) for executable UML. In this specification interruptible regions are excluded.

Comment: I am using SysMl in this example, I assume that it is still under this fUML, right ?

Comment: Yes. This is the only specification for precise semantics of activities. SysML adds a tiny bit but everything else is taken over from UML and fUML.